# Random telegraphic noise and Lorentzian noise power spectral density

Tags: noise, noise-spectral-density, power-spectral-density

[image]

Following the example of the Lorentzian noise power spectral density shown above ([ref](https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=901584)), I would like to clarify the following:

1. In the first figure (labeled by (c)), May I please know why the constant levels of the noise PSD increase? Is the change in  the only reason for this behavior?
2. In the second figure below it, the Lorentzian spectra show suppression and which is completely different from the behavior shown in the first figure. What is the physical significance of this behavior? I would like to understand what causes these two types of trend in Lorentzian generally, wherein in the first case, the corner frequency pushes inwards, and in the second case, the spectra shrink and corner frequency remains more or less the same.

It would be great to know your thoughts and explanation of these two behaviors!

Thanks a lot for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain it right away either. I think that the answer can be found in standard literature about signals theory.

Nevertheless, the following result of a small simulation in Matlab shows that the white (constant) noise directly scales with the pulse length \$\tau\$.

[image: Simulation results]

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

fs = 100e3;
Ts = 1/fs;
Tsim = 10;
t = 0 : Ts : Tsim-Ts;

tau = [ 100e-3, 10e-3, 1e-3 ];
pulsestart = [ 50e-3, 200e-3, 250e-3 ];

cmap = parula(length(tau)+1);
for i = 1 : length(tau)

    signal = zeros(length(t),1);
    signal(pulsestart(i)*fs+1:pulsestart(i)*fs+fs*tau(i)+1) = 1;

    NFFT = length(signal);
    [PSD_signal, f] = pwelch(signal, hann(length(t)), [], NFFT, fs);

    figure(1);

    subplot(1,2,1);
    plot(t.*1e3, signal, 'Color', cmap(i,:), 'LineWidth', 1.5, 'DisplayName', [ '\tau = ' num2str(tau(i)*1e3) ' ms' ]);
    hold on;
    grid on;
    xlabel('Time [ms]');
    ylabel('Amplitude [1]');
    xlim([0, 300e-3].*1e3);
    ylim([-0.5, 1.5]);

    subplot(1,2,2);
    loglog(f, PSD_signal, 'Color', cmap(i,:), 'LineWidth', 1.5, 'DisplayName', [ '\tau = ' num2str(tau(i)*1e3) ' ms' ]);
    hold on;
    grid on;
    xlabel('Frequency [Hz]');
    ylabel('Power Spectral Density [1/Hz]');

end

subplot(1,2,1);
legend('show');

subplot(1,2,2);
loglog(f, 1e-8./f.^2, 'k--', 'LineWidth', 1.5, 'DisplayName', '~ 1/f^2');
legend('show');
```